# Wordpress дублирует контент страницы при открытии по ссылке с параметрами Яндекс.Директа, как исправить?

Tags: wordpress, seo, яндекс-директ

Заказали рекламную кампанию в директе. Посетители переходят на сайт с объявлений по ссылкам, к которым дописаны параметры кампании, например:

example.com/buy_elefants/?utm_source=yandex_clk-adv&**type=search**

Обнаружил, что при открытии по таким ссылкам, контент на страницах стал дублироваться по 6 раз. То есть идет текст, картинка, потом опять тот же текст, та же картинка и т.д.

Экспериментируя со строкой URL обнаружил, что если убрать &type=search , все отображается нормально, дублирования нет. Но проблема в том, что **Яндекс этот параметр дописывает к ссылкам с кампании, убрать или переименовать его нельзя**.

1) В чем может быть причина этого глюка?

2) Если кто-нибудь сталкивался, как с этим бороться?

Comment: type не присутствует в списке зарезервированных параметров запроса WordPress. Не реагирует на него и WooCommerce. Видимо, плагин или тема используют такой параметр. Попробуйте отключить все плагины и сменить тему на стандартную.

Comment: А почему именно "type"? В метках же есть utm_medium для определения типа трафика — http://tools.yaroshenko.by/utm.php .

Comment: Скорее всего, где-то определен кастомная таксономия с таким слагом type

Comment: а кто вам сказал, что WordPress реагирует на utm_source? Я только что проверил - такого текста в ядре нет. Он просто игнорирует этот параметр

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте отфильтровать запрос на ранней стадии. В url всё останется как есть, но множественный вывод должен исчезнуть. Код надо добавить в functions.php вашей темы.

```
function init_filter() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['utm_source'] ) ) {
        unset( $_GET['utm_source'] );
        unset( $_GET['type'] );
    }
}

add_filter( 'init', 'init_filter' );
```